# Does one learning individually say the yehi ratzon?

Tags: tefilla, halacha-theory, torah-study

In every Schottenstein Gemara, the front cover comes equipped with two Yehi Ratzon prayers, one before and one after learning. These prayers include phrases that mention learning with a friend/partner. If one is learning alone, should one still say these tefillot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B:H

Hi, It seems to me from [Mishna Berura 110:35](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%97) that one who is learning by themselves  should still say the Yehi Ratzon however without saying "Shelo Yismach" and   "Vlo Yismichu betkelatam" (The Parts that talk about a chabura & Chavrusa/partner)